# Ubuntu 13.10 Nvidia display issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I've been attempting to fix an issue all day to no success.

I'm facing a problem that is only allowing me to use my inbuilt graphics card. I have three monitors and an Nvidia GeForce GTX 660; I've attempted to install the nvidia drivers but it seems to have failed somewhere.

It turns out I cannot post an image because I don't have the required reputation. I'll try to explain it. When I boot ubuntu, a box comes up notifying me there's a new version of ubuntu. The box has no border or minimize/maximize buttons, it's literally just the content.

If anybody knows a fix and needs to know any more information, I'd be happy to give you it. Thanks.

Edit: I've managed to fix the screen resolution issue for one of the monitors. The above problem still persists.
Edit: I've gone into the control manager thingy, enabled unity and everything it needed. Still doesn't seem to work. I've also tried reinstalling unity.

Comment: @123456 Tried before, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Having similar issues, I downloaded and installed the drivers from Nvidia itself.

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/75821/en-us  (for your model)

Follow their instructions to-heart, especially the part of not running X when installing (try "init 3") and everything should work as expected.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I've already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "It didn't work"? Did it not install at all? Did it install correctly but the problem persists? Did the behaviour change at all?